# Programming challenge: Competition for the best cat is coming

Tags: c#, algorithm

Recently I have attended a *coding challenge* and I was able score only 50%. There were few test cases failed executing my code, I am unable to *find reasons* for the failure in my code. So I have added the question and my code below. I appreciate your help in find the *reason for the failed test cases*.

**Requirement**

> Competition for the best cat is coming. The competition consists of
>   several duels. In each duel both cats are standing on an infinite line
>   facing each other. The older cat starts - it has to move towards his
>   opponent by 1 or 2 cat-units. Neither of them can go back, jump over
>   his opponent or share the same spot. The cat owners trained their cats
>   the best they could, so their pets play optimally. The cat that is
>   unable to make a move loses.

**Input**

> First line of the input contains number of tests t (t ≤ 1000). Each
>   test consists of 4 integers: age and position of the first cat and
>   then age and position of the second cat. No two cats have the same
>   age. No calculations in this task will exceed the number `2**31 - 1`.

**Output**

> For each test print 1 if the first cat wins and 0 otherwise.

**Example**

> **Input:**
>
> ```
> 1
> 10 1 9 5
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> 0
> ```
>
> **Explanation:** Cat `1` can move to either field `2` or `3`. In the next move
>   cat `2` regardless of the opponent's decision can *block* him and *win*.

**My Code**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Solution
{
    class Solution
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input1 = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
            var numOfTest = Convert.ToInt32(input1);

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfTest; i++)
            {
                var input2 = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                var catDetails = input2.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
                int result = -1;

                if (catDetails[0] == catDetails[2])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(-1);
                    break;
                }

                if(catDetails[0] > catDetails[2])
                    result = CalculateWinningResult(catDetails[0], catDetails[1], catDetails[2], catDetails[3], 1);
                else
                    result = CalculateWinningResult(catDetails[0], catDetails[1], catDetails[2], catDetails[3], 2);

                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }

        private static int CalculateWinningResult(int cat1Age, int cat1Position, int cat2Age, int cat2Position, int moveCat)
        {

            switch (moveCat)
            {
                case 1:

                    cat1Position = CalculateCatPosition(cat1Position, cat2Position);
                    if (cat1Position == 0)
                        return 0;
                    else
                        return CalculateWinningResult(cat1Age, cat1Position, cat2Age, cat2Position, 2);
                case 2:
                    cat2Position = CalculateCatPosition(cat2Position, cat1Position);
                    if (cat2Position == 0)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return CalculateWinningResult(cat1Age, cat1Position, cat2Age, cat2Position, 1);
            }
            return 0;
        }

        private static int CalculateCatPosition(int currentCatPosition, int opponentCatPosition)
        {
            int tempPosition;
            if (currentCatPosition > opponentCatPosition)
            {
                tempPosition = (currentCatPosition - 1);

                if (tempPosition <= opponentCatPosition)
                    return 0;
                else
                {
                    tempPosition = (currentCatPosition - 2);
                    if (tempPosition >= opponentCatPosition)
                        return 0;
                    else
                        currentCatPosition = tempPosition;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tempPosition = (currentCatPosition + 1);

                if (tempPosition <= opponentCatPosition)
                    return 0;
                else
                {
                    tempPosition = (currentCatPosition + 2);
                    if (tempPosition >= opponentCatPosition)
                        return 0;
                    else
                        currentCatPosition = tempPosition;
                }
            }

            return currentCatPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**[image: test case result]

Comment: Do we know what test cases 6-10 were?

Comment: Keara: Thanks for the reply, it was hidden. That is also one of the reason for me to post this question.

Answer (score 8):

Let's analyze the game. When a cat to move loses the game? First, it doesn't matter the *positions* of each cat but the *distance* between cats: 
if in `10 1 9 5` test a cat on move loses than `10 101 9 105` a cat on move loses as well.

Now, let's draw a simple table:

```
   distance | cat on move
   ----------------------
          0 | Loses (evident: he is blocked)
          1 | Wins
          2 | Wins
          3 | Loses
          4 | Wins
          5 | Wins
          6 | Loses 
          7 | Wins
          8 | Wins
          9 | Loses 
         10 | Wins
         11 | Wins
         12 | Loses 
....
```

Can you see *the pattern*? if distance between cats is *divisible by* `3` the cat on move loses; otherwise he (cat is "he" or "she", never "it"!) wins, his
strategy is to keep distance between he and his opponent be divisible by `3`. You can prove it by *induction*.

For Instance: for `10 1 9 5` case the distance is `5 - 1 - 1 == 3` and `3 % 3 == 0` (the distance is divisible by `3`) so the cat on move (`10` years old one) looses.

**Pseudo Code:** (let's not spoil the fun; please, implement **C#** code  yourself). When given 4 numbers `age1 x1 age2 x2` for cats' ages and initial locations we can find out the winner as followes:

```
 if ((Abs(x2 - x1) - 1) % 3 == 0) then // if distance divisible by 3?
   // Yes: Cat's on move loses
   if (age1 > age2) then 
     return 1
   else      
     return 0
 else  
   // No: Cat's on move wins
   if (age1 > age2) then 
     return 0
   else      
     return 1
```

Comment: This is similar to the strategy for that game where you remove 1 to 3 sticks from a pile. Upvoted, although my female cat wouldn't approve your stance on the choice of the default cat gender.

Comment: @Groo That's okay. Cats in general don't approve of much at all as far as humans are concerned.

Comment: "They" is an excellent gender-neutral pronoun to use for cats or anyone else! I asked my own cat, and he approves. Great answer.

Comment: I do not understand "Cat 1 can move to either field 2 or 3". Is it position number 2 or 3, or its 2 steps or 3 steps.

Comment: @vish: "Cat 1 can move to either field 2 or 3" - it's *position number* `2` or `3`; when at positon number `1`, the can can do `1` or `2` steps and appear at position number `2` or `3`

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and it passed all the test scenarios for me.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String n = sc.nextLine().trim();
    // Enter total number of tests
    int numOfTest = Integer.parseInt(n);
    // read cat details
    String catDetails = "";
    String[] catDetailsArr = new String[1];
    int[] catDetailsData = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfTest; i++) {

        catDetails = sc.nextLine().trim();

        catDetailsArr = catDetails.split(" ");



        for (int x = 0; x < catDetailsArr.length; x++) {
            catDetailsData[x] = Integer.parseInt(catDetailsArr[x]);
        }

        if (Math.abs(catDetailsData[3] - catDetailsData[1]) % 2 == 0)
            // Yes: Cat's on move loses
            if (catDetailsData[0] > catDetailsData[2])
                System.out.println("1");
            else
                System.out.println("0");
        else
        if (catDetailsData[0] > catDetailsData[2])
            System.out.println("0");
        else
            System.out.println("1");

    }
```

As per our understanding if diff in positions-1 is odd then the cat with lesser age will win else the older cat will win.